# Pagination problem with cache in Laravel: seeing the same results on every page

Tags: laravel, caching, pagination

I am using cache, but I see the same results on every page when I use pagination. How can I fix it?

For create, update, edit, save, I use Laravel Model Observer.

**My PostController**

```
public function allpost(Request $request)
    {
        if($request->cache =='flush')
        {
            Cache::flush();
        }
        $data  =[];
        $posts =Cache::get('posts',[]);

        if(empty($posts))
        {
            $posts = Post::paginate(10);
            Cache::forever('posts',$posts);

        }
        $data['posts'] = $posts ;
        return view('frontend.allpost',$data);
    }
```

**My ModelObserver**

```
<?php
namespace App\Observers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache;
class PostObserver
{
    public function created()
    {
        Cache::forget('posts');
    }

    public  function updated()
    {
        Cache::forget('posts');
    }
    public  function saved()
    {
        Cache::forget('posts');
    }

    public  function  deleted()
    {
        Cache::forget('posts');
    }
}
```

Comment: Of course it does, you just paginate the first 10 post. I think you need to cache all the post, then paginate the result.

Comment: How to paginate per page for cache?

Comment: You ``chunk`` the posts and get the part of chunked post match the pages. Please refer to Laravel collection here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#introduction

Answer (score 0):

this is a common issue.
You just cache 10 record and show this 10 record in all pages.
Your Cache function must write like this :

```
$posts = \Cache::remember('get-all-posts-' . request('page', 1), 3600, function () {
        return Post::paginate(10);
    });
```

above code , cache records of each page and your issue will be gone